# ArrayStoreException error with JNI and another thread

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

I'm attempting to read frames directly from a video file by using JNI and decoding the frames in native code, passing them back as a raw 3 byte BGR array. I'm also using jvmti's `SetTag` and `GetTag` to "tag" Java objects with a corresponding `struct` via pointer to `long long`.

I'm just having a tiny problem with JNI/JVMTI and threading. If a thread is started between calls to my native code (`read()`), the callback to Java causes the array to have a length of 0, while on the native side, the array still retains it's normal size. I've been under the assumption that it has to do with the `JNIEnv*`, since `JNIEnv`s are thread-specific, however, I don't see how starting an empty thread can effect this, nor can I find evidence that supports my assumption.

The code below causes the problem:

```
package ga.nurupeaches.imgmap.natives;

import ga.nurupeaches.imgmap.utils.YTRegexHelper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NativeVideoTest {

    public static final int WIDTH = 0, HEIGHT = 0;
    public static final String videoPath = YTRegexHelper.getDirectLinks("rnQBF2CIygg").get(0);
    private NativeVideo video;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.load("/home/tsunko/Gunvarrel/ImgMap-rw/src/main/cplusplus/libNativeVideo.so");
        NativeVideo.initialize(DebugCallbackHandler.class);

        NativeVideoTest test = new NativeVideoTest();
        test.nativeWork();
    }

    public NativeVideoTest() throws IOException {
        video = new NativeVideo(new DebugCallbackHandler(this, 1280, 720), WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public void nativeWork() throws InterruptedException {
        try{
            video.open(videoPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        video.read();
        new Thread().start();
        video.read(); // Returns 0 length array.
    }

}
```

`read()` is implemented as:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ga_nurupeaches_imgmap_natives_NativeVideo_read(JNIEnv* env, jobject jthis, jobject callback){
    NativeVideoContext* context = getContext(env, jthis, true);
    if(context == NULL){
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "read: reading frame" << std::endl;
    while(av_read_frame(context->formatContext, &(context->packet)) >= 0){
        std::cout << "read: recv packet" << std::endl;
        if(context->packet.stream_index == context->videoStreamId){
            std::cout << "read: recv video packet" << std::endl;
            avcodec_decode_video2(context->codecContext, context->rawFrame, &(context->frameFinished), &(context->packet));
            std::cout << "read: decoded video" << std::endl;

            if(context->frameFinished){
                std::cout << "read: finished frame; scaling" << std::endl;
                sws_scale(context->imgConvertContext, (const uint8_t* const*)context->rawFrame->data,
                            context->rawFrame->linesize, 0, context->codecContext->height,
                            context->rgbFrame->data, context->rgbFrame->linesize);
                std::cout << "read: scaled image; freeing packet and breaking loop" << std::endl;

                av_free_packet(&(context->packet));
                break;
            }
        }

        av_free_packet(&(context->packet));
    }

    std::cout << "read: init final returning" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "read: beforeSetByteArrayRegion javaArray@" << &(context->javaArray) << ";typeid=" << typeid(context->javaArray).name() << ";bufferSize=" << context->bufferSize << std::endl;
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(context->javaArray, 0, context->bufferSize, (jbyte*)(context->rgbFrame->data[0]));
    doCallback(env, callback, context->javaArray);
    std::cout << "read: afterSetByteArrayRegion javaArray@" << &(context->javaArray) << ";typeid=" << typeid(context->javaArray).name() << ";bufferSize=" << context->bufferSize << std::endl;
}
```

Log:

```
_initialize: found id
2764800
entry@getTag: checking jvmti
tag@getTag: null
entry@setTag: checking jvmti
tag@setTag: 140074857163376
entry _open: grabbing context
entry@getTag: checking jvmti
tag@getTag: 140074857163376
_open: nullcheck context
_open: setting source and formatContext
_open: opening input
_open: finding stream info
_open: finding video stream id
_open: fixing any 0 width/height
_open: finding decoder for codec
_open dbg: codecContext@0x7f65b81a6b20
_open dbg: codec_id=28
_open: opening decoder
_open: alloc frames
_open: nullcheck frames
_open: init swscale context
_open: init buffers
_open: reserving 2764800 bytes of memory for our buffer and etc.
entry@getTag: checking jvmti
tag@getTag: 140074857163376
read: reading frame
read: recv packet
read: recv video packet
read: decoded video
read: recv packet
read: recv video packet
read: decoded video
read: recv packet
read: recv video packet
read: decoded video
read: recv packet
read: recv video packet
read: decoded video
read: recv packet
read: recv video packet
read: decoded video
read: finished frame; scaling
read: scaled image; freeing packet and breaking loop
read: init final returning
read: beforeSetByteArrayRegion javaArray@0x7f65b81a6b10;typeid=P11_jbyteArray;bufferSize=2764800
read: afterSetByteArrayRegion javaArray@0x7f65b81a6b10;typeid=P11_jbyteArray;bufferSize=2764800
entry@getTag: checking jvmti
tag@getTag: 140074857163376
read: reading frame
read: recv packet
read: recv video packet
read: decoded video
read: finished frame; scaling
read: scaled image; freeing packet and breaking loop
read: init final returning
read: beforeSetByteArrayRegion javaArray@0x7f65b81a6b10;typeid=P11_jbyteArray;bufferSize=2764800
data.length=0;rawImage.length=2764800
read: afterSetByteArrayRegion javaArray@0x7f65b81a6b10;typeid=P11_jbyteArray;bufferSize=2764800
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at ga.nurupeaches.imgmap.natives.DebugCallbackHandler.handleData(DebugCallbackHandler.java:30)
    at ga.nurupeaches.imgmap.natives.NativeVideo.read(Native Method)
    at ga.nurupeaches.imgmap.natives.NativeVideo.read(NativeVideo.java:31)
    at ga.nurupeaches.imgmap.natives.NativeVideoTest.nativeWork(NativeVideoTest.java:33)
    at ga.nurupeaches.imgmap.natives.NativeVideoTest.main(NativeVideoTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Relevent code for anything else is available at https://github.com/CirnoTheGenius/ImgMap-rw/tree/master/src/main/cplusplus

As a note, pardon me for any mistakes I've made in C++; I'm still relativly new to it.

Comment: What do `getContext()` and `doCallback()` do?  If you're saving anything from one JNI call and using it in another, you're likely to see inconsistent results at best.  And `(jbyte*)(context->rgbFrame->data[0])` looks wrong to me, unless `rgbFrame->data` is an array of arrays.  That code is taking the value stored in the first element of the `data` array and casting it to a `jbyte *`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `getContext()` fetches a signed `long long` that was tagged to a jobject via JVMTI's `SetTag(jobject, jlong)'; it returns either null or casts the `long long` to and returns as a `NativeVideoContext*`. It can optionally throw an `IOException`. As for `doCallback()`, it's merely defined (and inlined) to call `env->CallVoidMethod(callback, id, arr);`. As for `rgbFrame->data`, it is an array of pointers to the image plane data (defined at [link](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.6/structAVPicture.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Java byte arrays via `NewByteArray`, I ended up just passing a direct `ByteBuffer` and getting the `ByteBuffer`'s memory region address and using `memcpy` to copy `context->rgbFrame->data[0]` into it, then calling `doCallback()` without any arguments to notify the callback handler that it was finished.